# Check whether Internet is on or off in Xamarin Android

Tags: android, xamarin, mvvmcross, internet-connection

I am working on Xamarin Android Application.Before proceed to my next fragment I want to check **Internet Connection** and inform user about it ? How can i implement that ?And how to refresh whole fragment after user switch-on the internet?
Any advice or suggestion will be appreciated !

Comment: search before ask. see [this](https://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/ios/network/reachability/detect_if_network_is_available/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
NetworkStatus internetStatus = Reachability.InternetConnectionStatus();

if(!Reachability.IsHostReachable("http://google.com")) {
    // Put alternative content/message here
}
else
{
    // Put Internet Required Code here
}
```

Comment: Reachability class doesn't exist in the current context!

Answer (score 13):

To get the network status you could use the following method in your activity:

```
 public bool IsOnline()
    {
        var cm = (ConnectivityManager)GetSystemService(ConnectivityService);
        return cm.ActiveNetworkInfo == null ? false : cm.ActiveNetworkInfo.IsConnected;
    }
```

If I understood you correctly from this sentence: `And how to refresh whole fragment after user switch-on the internet`, You want to detect, whenever any changes in the connection status happens, Therefore you absolutely need to use [broadcast receivers](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Android.Content.BroadcastReceiver/).

First of all you should implement a broadcast receiver with a simple Event named `ConnectionStatusChanged` as follows:

```
[BroadcastReceiver()]
public class NetworkStatusBroadcastReceiver : BroadcastReceiver
{

    public event EventHandler ConnectionStatusChanged;

    public override void OnReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        if (ConnectionStatusChanged != null)
            ConnectionStatusChanged(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }
}
```

Then in your activity (in `OnCreate()` method for example, It doesn't matter) create an instance of that receiver and register it:

```
var _broadcastReceiver = new NetworkStatusBroadcastReceiver();
_broadcastReceiver.ConnectionStatusChanged += OnNetworkStatusChanged;
Application.Context.RegisterReceiver(_broadcastReceiver, 
new IntentFilter(ConnectivityManager.ConnectivityAction));
```

Here is the body of the event handler:

```
private void OnNetworkStatusChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       if(IsOnline()){
        Toast.MakeText(this, "Network Activated", ToastLength.Short).Show();
        // refresh content fragment.
       }
    }
```

To cut the long story short, `NetworkStatusBroadcastReceiver` receives any change in the network status of the device and invokes the `ConnectionStatusChanged` (When user enables data traffic or WiFi connection), Then you catch that event and check for network status using `IsOnline()` method. Very simple.

Comment: the Compiler Says  `new IntentFilter(ConnectivityManager.ConnectivityAction));` is  depricated!

Answer (score 4):

You can use the MVVMCross plugin : [Connectivity](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/Xamarin.Plugins/tree/master/Connectivity)

It wil expose a boolean

```
/// <summary>
/// Gets if there is an active internet connection
/// </summary>
bool IsConnected { get; }
```

and a delegate on change state

```
/// <summary>
/// Event handler when connection changes
/// </summary>
event ConnectivityChangedEventHandler ConnectivityChanged;
```

Comment: no tutorial on how to try it for someone who is a beginner in xamarin.

Comment: Above connectivity library is good, but it had several device compatibility  problem, you need to make sure it is supporting well on other devices.